# Use editable div on multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I want to manipulate inputs, and for that I need to create editable divs that will replace them.

```js
let exemplo = document.getElementById("exemplo");
exemplo.style.display = "none";

let editableDiv = document.createElement("divEditable");

editableDiv.contentEditable = true;
editableDiv.style.border = "1px solid black";
editableDiv.style.width = "300px";

exemplo.parentNode.insertBefore(editableDiv, exemplo.nextSibling);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
      <input type="text" id="exemplo" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

From this div I'll do some manipulations. The problem is that I can only use this editable div only on one input, and I have MANY inputs.

How could I do it without polluting my code by creating multiple divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all `input` using [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and the iterate and apply the same logic that you have used.

```js
let inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')];

inputs.forEach(el => {

  el.style.display = "none";

  let editableDiv = document.createElement("divEditable");
  editableDiv.contentEditable = true;
  editableDiv.style.border = "1px solid black";
  editableDiv.style.width = "300px";

  el.parentNode.insertBefore(editableDiv, el.nextSibling);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <input type="text" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need grouped selector of input like

```
document.getElementsByClassName("exemplo");//is Array
//or
document.querySelectorAll(".exemplo");//is Array ('.' mean class)
//Need to change id="exemplo" --> class="exemplo"
```

or (Example on [Nidhin Joseph's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58161449/11767915) answer) by tag

```
x.getElementsByTagName("input"); //is Array
//or
document.querySelectorAll("input"); //is Array
```

```js
let exemplo_list = document.getElementsByClassName("exemplo");

for (i = 0; i < exemplo_list.length; i++) {
  input_div(exemplo_list[i])
}

function input_div(exemplo) {
  exemplo.style.display = "none";

  let editableDiv = document.createElement("divEditable");

  editableDiv.contentEditable = true;
  editableDiv.style.border = "1px solid black";
  editableDiv.style.width = "300px";

  exemplo.parentNode.insertBefore(editableDiv, exemplo.nextSibling);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    input 1
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="exemplo" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">
    <br> input 2
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="exemplo" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```